# Too many fragmented files, also getting memory dumping message, and getting stuck of my machine. what should I do to fix all these

Tags: windows-xp, hard-drive, memory, dump, memory-leaks

My laptop is bit old now. It has an IDE HDD and I am using windows XP. From time to time, I get memory dumping message. and also when I am working, from time to time, the machine gets stuck and I need to reboot using the power button.

Also, I noticed that HDD free space is often reduced. For example, if it is 2.0 GB in the morning, then after a couple of hours it becomes, 1.4 GB...  To see the configuration of my laptop, please refer to the image below:

[image]

Despite having defragmented my drive, it is still very fragmented (see below).

[image]

So, how can I fix this fragmentation issue and all my other problems?

Comment: How much RAM do you have?

Comment: @cybernard: its  1GB

Comment: If your laptop supports 2gb. Double your memory and it will be a lot happier.

Comment: @cybernard how will this affect the fragmentation or disk usage issues? It _might_ help for the freezes (I doubt it though, this is an old machine and an old OS, designed to run fine on 1gb of RAM) but it will not change any of the other problems.

Comment: @terdon  If Windows has a large cache it will not be under pressure to constantly write new data to the hard drive.  Therefore, it will write files all at once and thus decrease the likely hood of creating fragmented files.  This might seem like a small thing, but when windows is constantly shrinking and growing the swap file it actually does matter.

Comment: @gnp First I updated my other answer. Second the reduction in hard drive is probably the swap file growing and shrinking depending on how many programs you have open.  When you the have the least free space, Start click on Run type: command <Enter> dir c:\ /ah <Enter> see how big the pagefile.sys size.

Comment: @cybernard that's a very good point, I hadn't thought of that.

Comment: I would rule out a hardware issue before doing anything else. Make sure your heatsink is free of dust and run something like [memtest86](http://memtest.org).

Answer (score 2):

These are both better than Windows Defragger.

> Raxco makes a product called PerfectDisk 12.5

[Defraggler](http://www.piriform.com/defraggler)

I forgot to address your free space issue.
Either do like the other guy suggested and format and reload, OR

Launch Services (start->run services.msc )
turn off windows update
delete this folder:  C:\Windows\SoftwareDistribution
turn on windows update

Show all files including hidden and system files.

Either in c:\windows or c:\windows\system32

You will see around 100+ folders starting with the name "$Uninstall"
Delete all of them you will not be uninstalling any patches.

Reduce system restore to 200mb.

Unless you absolutely need it turn hibernation off that saves as much memory as you have or 1gb in your case. (hiberfil.sys is a hidden file in the root folder)

sfc /cleanup

Let me know how much space that frees up.

Have you ever done a complete check of your hard drive?
Click on Start then Run
type: command

chkdsk /r c:
Say YES to do it when you restart the computer.
Restart the computer and it should take a couple hours depending on hard drive size.

Comment: Defraggler has a free edition with NO support.

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet would probably be to back everything up, format your drive and do a clean reinstall. Considering your hardware (the t2050 was released in 2008) I am guessing you have a 4-5 year old laptop. If it has been running the same installation of XP for all this time, you are likely to be full of various bloatware.

Even if you're not, Windows accumulates crap over time and its performance falls. These could be stray registry entries, malware, bloatware, extreme fragmentation etc. If you simply wipe everything, format and reinstall you will probably see a large improvement in performance.

That said, a laptop's life expectancy is not much more than 4 years. Most laptops develop problems after a few years and very few survive much longer. You should really consider upgrading or at least make sure to take regular backups.

Comment: thanks for the comments. one of friends told me to remove the RAM and touch the pins and fix it again. would it be work?

Comment: @gnp I have no idea.